# Как решить проблему '_TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'name'?

Tags: django

```
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-6">
                {% for test in posts %}
                <div class="post-block">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <h3>{{ test.title|truncatechars_html:30 }}</h3>
                                <h6>Теги: {{ test.tags }}</h6>
                                <h4 class="text-right">Дата: {{ test.date_pub }}</h4>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-11">
                                <p class="col_for_main">{{ test.text|truncatechars_html:100 }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="post/{{ test.id }}">Read</a>
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Add to favorite</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-3"></div>
        </div>


def home(request):

    posts = reversed(Post.objects.all())
    context = {
        "posts": posts
    }
    return render(request, "mr_blog.html", context)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_pub = models.DateField('date_pub')
    tags = TaggableManager()
    test = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=0)

def __str__(self):

    return "{0}".format(self.id)
```

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки. В приведённом коде нет ничего, что могло бы приводить к такое ошибке.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Q2yAIB_k-8U

Вот в этом видео весь текст ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
<h6>Теги: {{ test.tags.all|join:", " }}</h6>
...
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, всё в порядке.